# Need help chasing down: Exception while building using Provider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, exception, flutter-provider

I'm trying to learn Flutter and become more acquainted with passing data around. So i have this very simple app here that is a sort of complicated version of this: [Provider version flutter starter demo](https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/master/provider_counter)

Like I said I'm trying to get acquainted, and I'm a relatively green dev. I'm creating this demo to learn StateManagement as well as Persistence.

My goal with this post, is to get help to fix this issue and also know what I'm doing wrong.

So far I have tried moving a few things around and some typical searches but can't seem to figure out specifically what I'm doing wrong here compared with others who are getting the same error.

The app works fine, exactly as expected, no crash and as far as my green grass eyes can tell my code is structured exactly like the Flutter example (with respect to the Provider StateManagement). However I'm getting this error in the console:

```
======== Exception caught by foundation library ====================================================
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for Keeper:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This _InheritedProviderScope<Keeper> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: _InheritedProviderScope<Keeper>
  value: Instance of 'Keeper'
  listening to value
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: Consumer<Keeper>
  dirty
  dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<Keeper>]
```

Page 1

```
class ScreenOne extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String id = 'screen_one';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Page One',
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
      body: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  CustomTextBoxes(title: 'Screen One'),
                  Consumer<Keeper>(
                    builder: (_, keeper, child) => Text(
                      '${keeper.pageOneValue}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  CustomTextBoxes(title: 'Screen Two'),
                  Consumer<Keeper>(
                    builder: (_, keeper, child) => Text(
                      '${keeper.pageTwoValue}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  CustomTextBoxes(title: 'Total'),
                  Consumer<Keeper>(
                    builder: (_, keeper, child) => Text(
                      '${keeper.addCounters()}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  CustomButton(
                    text: 'Screen 2',
                    function: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, ScreenTwo.id);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: CustomFloatingButton(
        function: () {
          var counter = context.read<Keeper>();
          counter.incrementCounterOne();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

"Keeper"

```
class Keeper with ChangeNotifier {
  int pageOneValue = 0;
  int pageTwoValue = 0;
  int totalValue = 0;

  void incrementCounterOne() {
    pageOneValue += 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void incrementCounterTwo() {
    pageTwoValue += 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int addCounters() {
    totalValue = pageOneValue + pageTwoValue;
    notifyListeners();
    return totalValue;
  }
}
```

Main

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => Keeper(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      initialRoute: ScreenOne.id,
      routes: {
        ScreenOne.id: (context) => ScreenOne(),
        ScreenTwo.id: (context) => ScreenTwo()
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling any of the Keeper functions() from outside the build method ?

Comment: As far as I can tell (with limited understanding of what that means) no. All calls are inside the build method. Possibly the custom widgets cause such a shift???  But even they aren't calling Keeper or and provider methods...

Comment: Okay, Can you try changing the ScreenOne from stateless to stateful widget.

Comment: No luck, tried converting both screens to Stateful and same error shows on build, rebuild or hot reload. Do I need to post more code? Pretty simple... Page 2 has exact same code except title of course... not much to this, confusing... Also tried converting MyApp to stateful with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in calling `addCounters()` inside your `build` method. `addCounters()` calls `notifyListeners()` that triggers a `setState()`.

This cannot be perform within your `build` function. It can only be performed later at the request of a User action. For example, inside the `onPressed` of a button as you do for the `incrementCounterOne()`.

Instead of computing and storing the total value of your two counters, you could use a getter:

**Keeper:**

```
class Keeper with ChangeNotifier {
  int pageOneValue = 0;
  int pageTwoValue = 0;

  int get totalValue => pageOneValue + pageTwoValue;

  void incrementCounterOne() {
    pageOneValue += 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void incrementCounterTwo() {
    pageTwoValue += 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**ScreenOne:**

```
Consumer<Keeper>(
  builder: (_, keeper, child) => Text(
    '${keeper.totalValue}', // addCounters()}',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 20.0),
  ),
),
```